# How to get access to button instances generated in TinyMCE 4 from outside of onPostRender method?

Tags: button, tinymce, toolbar, tinymce-4

I want to disable all buttons in TinyMCE4 after editor instantiation.  TinyMCE4 removed the ability to access the buttons inside the controlManager.  In TinyMCE3, you could do this:

```
_.each(editor.controlManager.controls, function (property, index, controls) {
    controls[property.id].setDisabled(disabled);
});
```

It seems the only way to access the encapsulated button instance that gets generated by TinyMCE4 is through the postRender method:

```
editor.addButton('example', {
    title: 'My title',
    image: '../js/tinymce/plugins/example/img/example.gif',
    onPostRender: function () {
        // this refers to button instance generated by TinyMCE4, where disabling/enabling functionality is available
    }
});
```

I am working on a custom CMS with third party WYSIWYG plugin integrations so I don't have the ability to modify the onPostRender method for all of the buttons that will get used in the editor.  Is there any way to access the toolbar or button instance from the editor object so I can call its `disabled` method as documented in the source here:

```
  /**
   * Sets/gets the disabled state on the control.
   *
   * @method disabled
   * @param {Boolean} state Value to set to control.
   * @return {Boolean/tinymce.ui.Control} Current control on a set operation or current state on a get.
   */
  // disabled: function(state) {} -- Generated
```

I'm using TinyMCE 4.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`editor.theme.panel.rootControl.controlIdLookup` has references to all the buttons in the toolbar.